# How to change SQL query to work in Vertica?

Tags: sql, oracle, vertica

we have Oracle 11.2 DB in which SQL query :

```
SELECT STREAM , SUBSTREAM, SEQUENCE_ID + 1 SEQ, FILE_NAME_TIME,TASK_START_TIME, VALIDITY_TOKEN
from time_gap_files s1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL from time_gap_files s2 where s2.SEQUENCE_ID=s1.SEQUENCE_ID+
(select DISTINCT FILE_GAP from time_gap_files_rules R, time_gap_files S where
S.STREAM=R.STREAM)) ORDER BY SEQUENCE_ID;
```

works fine.

But when I run same query in Vertica 6 (with same database structure) - I've got error message:
ERROR 2089:  A correlated column in a subquery expression is not supported.

Last SQL sub-query `(select DISTINCT FILE_GAP from time_gap_files_rules R, time_gap_files S where S.STREAM=R.STREAM)` should return only one number and works fine separately. But not as sub-query in query.

How do I change my query to satisfy strict rules of Vertica SQL ?

Tables structure:

```
time_gap_files                                                        COLUMN_NAME     DATA_TYPE TYPE_NAME COLUMN_SIZE 
--------------- --------- --------- ----------- 
UNIQUE_ID       -5        Integer   19          
STREAM          12        Varchar   20          
SUBSTREAM       12        Varchar   20          
SEQUENCE_ID     2         Numeric   38          
FILE_NAME_TIME  93        Timestamp 26          
CREATION_TIME   93        Timestamp 26          
PROCESSING_TIME 93        Timestamp 26          
FILE_NAME       12        Varchar   100         
RECORD_COUNT    2         Numeric   38          
VALIDITY_TOKEN  -5        Integer   19          
TASK_START_TIME 93        Timestamp 26


time_gap_files_rules
COLUMN_NAME    DATA_TYPE TYPE_NAME COLUMN_SIZE 
-------------- --------- --------- ----------- 
STREAM         12        Varchar   20          
SEQUENCE_RULE  12        Varchar   20          
MIN_SEQ_NUMBER 2         Numeric   38          
MAX_SEQ_NUMBER 2         Numeric   38          
TIME_GAP       2         Numeric   38          
TIME_DEPTH     12        Varchar   20          
FILE_GAP       -5        Integer   19
```

Comment: post you tbl structure here !

Comment: Just for future reference Vertica is based on the PostgreSQL engine in regards to SQL. So if you start your search with how to do things in PostgreSQL 99 times out of 100 it will work with Vertica.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding limit-clause obviously to your sub-query: `(select DISTINCT FILE_GAP from time_gap_files_rules R, time_gap_files S where S.STREAM=R.STREAM limit 1)`

Answer (score 0):

**Try to run your query using this script :**

```
SELECT 
STREAM , 
SUBSTREAM,
SEQUENCE_ID + 1 SEQ,
FILE_NAME_TIME,
TASK_START_TIME,
VALIDITY_TOKEN
from time_gap_files s1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT NULL from time_gap_files s2
,time_gap_files s3 
where s2.SEQUENCE_ID=(s3.SEQUENCE_ID
+
(
select 
DISTINCT FILE_GAP 
    from time_gap_files_rules R, time_gap_files S where
S.STREAM=R.STREAM
))
) ORDER BY SEQUENCE_ID;
```

see Vertica sub query restriction here https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ProgrammersGuide/Queries/SubqueryRestrictions.htm

Comment: can you post some data sample here !